# How to watch for average daily value traded?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I need to watch on specific stocks for the average daily value traded. The average would be on a period of days, let's say 10. In native monetary value of the stock itself (ie: USD, EUR...).

Also it needs to be trimmed for 10% of the outliers, which is the aggregate percentage of data points from the top and bottom tails that will be excluded from the data set.

How can I achieve that with TradingView? Is there an existing Indicator? Or would I need a custom Pine Script? If so, can you guide me through the basis of such a script?

Thanks!

Edit: adding my script in current state

```
//@version=5
source = (volume * ohlc4)
indicator("Average Daily Value Traded", overlay=false, precision=0)
// Daily Value Traded
plot(source, "Daily", color.green, style = plot.style_columns)
// Average Daily Value Traded
length = 20 // How many bars back?
average = ta.sma(source, length)
plot(average, "Average", color.red, 2)
```

Comment: I found nothing in TV that provides this info. How would you calculate it if you would need to do it yourself? This relies heavily on time frame. As you have `Volume` for a specific time frame it could be the base for the calculation but still you need to split the traded Volume (with some weight or algorithm) among the OHLC prices and then could you calculate the average.

Comment: Thank you @karatedog I think I have something using the sma function. With 10 bars back as the length and making sure my chart is in days (D), then I got a moving average of volume per price on last 10 days. I added my code to the post.

But now I don't know how to implement the 10% outliers to be trimmed off?

Comment: Daily traded Volume is different from daily traded Value. Getting the SMA on Volume will not give you any data about the daily Value. You can only assume that, on a daily chart, say, 25% of the daily Volume was traded at the Open price, 25% of that Volume was traded at the High, Low and Close prices respectively. Then you have a synthetic daily Value price (which will be off from reality). You can go deeper in the time frame and as an extreme, calculate the daily Value based on the 1m chart, calculating it per candle, then averaging it for the whole day. This would be closer to reality.